# How to manage HTC Vive controllers power programmatically?

Tags: htc-vive, openvr, steamvr

Is it possible to power off Vive controller/tracker programmatically?

I see there is an option in SteamVR under each tracked device, but I could not find any references.
The only thing I found is polling events of entering and leaving standby mode via OpenVR api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I've found is

1. Getting serial number of connected wireless dongle via OpenVR using `Prop_ConnectedWirelessDongle_String` property.
2. Calling `lighthouse_console` with arguments `/serial %serialNumber% poweroff`. This tool is provided by SteamVR and located at `SteamVR\tools\lighthouse\bin\win32(64)` folder.

Note that if device is connected via USB, it will not power off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currenlty using this piece of code as there is no legit way to do this. but this seems to work in my case.

```
void Start () {

    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\SteamVR\\tools\\lighthouse\\bin\\win64\\lighthouse_console.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/serial 81F6B76702 poweroff";

    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    process.Start();

}
```